# Ramda - how to add new property to objects in array

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to add a new property to each object in the array. My test array:

```
const array = [
  {
    "name": 'Test'
  },
  {
    "name": 'Test2'
  }
]
```

I tried to use `R.assoc('selected', false, array);` but it didn't work as expected.
As a result, I would like to get:

```
const array = [
  {
    "name": 'Test',
    "selected": false
  },
  {
    "name": 'Test2',
    "selected: false
  }
]
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R.assoc` works by making a shallow clone of an object, and setting/updating a property. In this case, you need to handle an array of objects. Use `R.map` to iterate the array, and create a new array with transformed cloned objects by applying `R.assoc`:

```js
const fn = R.map(R.assoc('selected', false));

const array = [{"name":"Test"},{"name":"Test2"}];

const result = fn(array);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Simple mistake again. Thank you :)

Comment: It happens to all of us. You're welcome :)

Comment: If you're looking for how to create a new property based on values from other properties from the same object, see this answer from the same author https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63208320/transform-an-object-with-a-new-property-derived-from-original-properties-in-ramd